# Creating a new variable conditional: 3/12 responses among existing variables == 1

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with 12 variables. I want to create a variable which should = 1 if at least 3/12 of my existing responses==1. The data set looks somewhat like;

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  <<new_var>>
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0      1
1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0      1
1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your variables get the values of `0` and `1`, then you can try to simply sum the rows:

```
data$new_var <- as.numeric(rowSums(data) >= 3)
```

So for your case:

```
# this is only example data frame
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
")

data$new_var <- as.numeric(rowSums(data) >= 3)
```

The result:

```
> data
  a b c d e f g h i j k l new_var
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0       0
2 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0       1
3 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0       1
4 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0       0
```